# Illegal Invocation Error with Arrow Functions

Tags: javascript

I am getting error executing the following code:

```
let myFunc4 = (nameFunction) => ("Hello " + nameFunction() + ".");
let printName = (nameFunction, printFunction) => printFunction(myFunc4(nameFunction));
printName(function () { return "Adam" }, console.log);
```

It's supposed to return **"Hello Adam"** but I get the following error:

```
 Error: (SystemJS) Illegal invocation TypeError: Illegal invocation at printName
```

I am finding it hard to spot where the problem is after spending much time looking at the console logs.

Comment: It returns `Hello Adam.`.

Comment: @Kinduser that is what its suppose to return but am getting error

Comment: @EddyFreeman your nodejs version is too old,that not support the arrow functions.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. What JavaScript engine are you using to run the code? Are you transpiling it first? Have you tested this your [mcve] is complete and that the problem isn't coming from a line you omitted from the question?

Comment: @holi-java You might be right. It seems my nodejs might be the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.  Please run snippet.  Are you running in node?  If so, update it to latest version.

```js
let myFunc4 = (nameFunction) => ("Hello " + nameFunction() + ".");
let printName = (nameFunction, printFunction) => printFunction(myFunc4(nameFunction));
printName(function() {
  return "Adam"
}, console.log);
```